# Is there anyway to get the NDC code for a drug from the drug enforcement report fields?

Tags: openfda, json

Given the fields acquired from a drug enforcement report:

- country
- reason_for_recall
- classification
- recall_number
- recalling_firm
- initial_firm_notification
- code_info
- product_quantity
- event_id
- product_type
- recall_initiation_date
- distribution_pattern
- state
- product_description
- voluntary_mandated
- report_date
- status

Is there anyway to obtain the NDC code for the drug associated with that recall?

https://api.fda.gov/drug/enforcement.json?limit=10&search=report_date:%2220141105%22

Answer (score 1):

This page explains that in about half of enforcement reports, there is a special `openfda` section that has identifiers (like the NDC) for the drug involved in the recall.

https://open.fda.gov/drug/enforcement/reference/#openfda-fields

However, it points out that the section only exists in about half of the reports because an exact match on the drug name is required to create the link between the enforcement report and the NDC. It looks like enforcement reports have text descriptions and drug names can be written in all kinds of ways, which would make matching somewhat challenging.